# 310 too many redirects after moving drupal site to fast-cgi

Tags: fastcgi, drupal

Here is trouble:
 When i follow this link - http://znak.net.ua it rewrites to http://znak.net.ua/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ and i got Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

This happend when i start using fast-cgi insteed of mod_php
  Here is my .htaccess:

ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php


<IfModule mod_php4.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A1209600
  ExpiresByType text/html A1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://znak.net.ua/ru/$1 [L,R=301]




  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ru/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using `mod_fastcgi` with Apache? Also, is there a reason you're loading php4 and php5?

Answer (score 1):

The following line causes that behavior:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://znak.net.ua/ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This says, for any request containing any characters (or none at all), redirect it to `http://znak.net.ua/ru/`, followed by the requested URL.  If this site is, itself, `http://znak.net.ua/`, then that means that a request for `/ru/` will be converted to `ru/` (since we're in an effective `<Directory>` context due to `.htaccess`), which will in turn send us to `http://znak.net.ua/ru/ru/`.  From there, you can easily imagine what happens on the next round when the request for `/ru/ru/` comes in.

It's hard to imagine what you're trying to do with this line, so I confess that I don't really know how to "fix" it.  If you can share your intention, I'm happy to offer a solution.